# PDF fromdata Controls not visible in iOS Ipad

Tags: angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I have PDF with multiple input form controls like TextBox and CheckBox, Using Chrome as a Browser. In iOS Ipad the controls not visibile when pdf in actual size.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb0a9.png)
But I ZoomIn that pdf that controls are now visible.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yMWB.png)

This pdf Form working fine in PC Web and Android Tab. This issue occurred only in Ipad.

Any ideas?

To know some solutions